# I'm trying to mock Jersey WebResource with Mockito, and can't do it

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, jersey, mockito

This is my code ([Jersey 1.4](http://jersey.java.net/) + [Mockito 1.8.5](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2)):

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
public FooTest {
  @Test public shouldMakeAHttpCall() {
    WebResource wr = mock(WebResource.class);
    doReturn(wr).when(wr).accept(anyVararg());
    doReturn("some text").when(wr).get(String.class);
  }
}
```

Compiler says:

```
cannot find symbol: method accept(java.lang.Object)
location: class com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource
```

There is something wrong with `anyVargarg()`, but what exactly?

Comment: There will be no mocking of Jersey.  MTV has already taken care of that for us.

Comment: Note that WebResource.accept doesn't return a WebResource object, it returns a WebResource.Builder.  I agree with you that anyVargarg() is the problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
doReturn(wr).when(wr).accept((MediaType) anyVararg());
```

Comment: The cast was the key. Even if it seems unnatural to cast like this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
WebResource wr = mock(WebResource.class);
when(wr.accept(anyObject())).thenReturn(wr);
when(wr.get(anyString()).thenReturn("some text");
```

Comment: Maybe try anyObject() instead of anyVararg(). Just edited the answer.